# Android GL_FLOAT convert to GL_SHORT in an OpenGL ES vertex array

Tags: android, opengl-es

```
float coords[] = {
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
  1.1f, 2.3f, 0.0f, 
}
```

i have a simple coord array in floats. How I can convert it to GL_SHORT?

so not this: gl.glVertexPointer(dimension, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

but: gl.glVertexPointer(dimension, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, mVertexBuffer_short);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers would be exactly the same (as in `{0,0,0, 0,1,0, ...}`).  If you had fractions you'd have to apply a suitable scaling matrix at render time so that you could represent your points as integers.